# How to validate the empty string in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I want to validate the string value after getting in the below parser delegate method

I have tried like [string length]>0 ,(string !=NULL) in if condition still blank string is printed in the NSlog.So what is the efficient method to validate the sting.I have used the below code.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {   
    if ([elemName isEqualToString:@"productName"]) {
        if (!prodStringValue) {
            prodStringValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:50];
        }
        [prodStringValue appendString:string];
        if(prodStringValue && [prodStringValue length]>0 && (prodStringValue !=NULL))
        {
            prodNameStr = prodStringValue;
        NSLog(@"productName:%@",prodNameStr);
        }
        if(string && [string length]>0 && (string !=NULL))
        {
            prodNameStr = string;
            NSLog(@"productName:%@",string);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/better-way-to-check-empty-string.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this below few lines of code

```
NSString *trimedstr  = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


if(trimedstr != [NSNull null]&& ![trimedstr isEqualToString:@""])
{
    if([trimedstr length]>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", trimedstr);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to trim a string that could be null it would probably throw an exception? If it couldn't be null than that comparison doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have whitespaces in this "empty" string? Be sure to delete them using

```
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check if `[string length] == 0`. This will check if it's a valid but empty string (`@""`) as well as if its nil, since calling `length` on nil will also return 0.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following code instead of all three checks, I suppose.

```
[prodStringValue isEqualToString:@""];
```

And, BTW

```
if (prodStringValue)
```

equals to

```
if (prodStringValue != nil) // nil = NULL in objc
```

Comment: In Obj-C, `nil` is a *NULL id*, there is still `NULL` for normal, non-id pointers. Practically, there is no difference between nil and NULL, though.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: huh? MacTypes.h: #define nil NULL

Answer (score 2):

```
if (str == Nil)
```

Try This. Works For Me.

Answer (score 1):

In case of string is NULL and you check it's length then it will crash.
so you may try.

```
string  = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


if(string != [NSNull null])
{
    if([string length]>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        [str isEqualToString:@""]
```

It is best way for nil string.