# how to check if there is any item which is to be added in array is empty

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsarray

how to check that if any item String is added in array and that is empty so how to remove that from array at run time 
  i have array like

```
    NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:iphone,droid,blackberry,donotUse,window,other,nil];
```

i want that if iphone is empty at runtime it should not be in the array.

becuase if it is empy then it does not show rest of the values so how to fix this issue.

Comment: simple , if(iPhone != nil ) {add it to array otherwise not}.

Comment: if its string then use stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet Method to check whether its empty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361650/how-to-validate-the-empty-string-in-objective-c. It think this is answer of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSMutableArray` instead and only add if it is different from `nil`:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if([iphone length] > 0)
  [arr addObject:iphone];
...
```

Comment: he asked how to check if its an empty string. so for that I think stringByTrimmingCharInSet method is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:iphone,droid,blackberry,donotUse,window,other,nil];
NSMutableArray *cleanArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0 ; i < [myArray count]; i++)
{
   if([[myArray objectAtIndex:i] length])
       [cleanArray addObject:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(NSString *str in myArray)
{
 if (str != (id)[NSNull null] || str.length != 0 )
 {
    [arrValues addObject:str]; 
 }
}
```